# Ruby on Rails 4: How to include Javascript and CSS?

Tags: javascript, css, ruby-on-rails

I'm new to rails and I'm building an application using rails 4. I want to create a page that uses JQuery, another 3rd party javascript library available via CDN, a 3rd party CSS library available via CDN, my own javascript, and my own CSS. I need to use the:

```
jQuery(function($) {
  ...
});
```

function to execute some javascript when the page is loaded and this only seems to work if I put the call to jQuery(function($)... in the  of the document.

I want JQuery to be included in all my apps pages, but everything else I mentioned above I only want included in this particular page.

What should I do? I've been reading various things online and I'm feeling confused. Should I download the 3rd party resources and include them somewhere under the vendor directory? If I do that, how I can I make sure they're only included in that particular page? Isn't downloading 3rd party resources all about leveraging the asset pipeline to combine everything into one huge JS file so there are less HTTP requests? So, if I only want this 3rd party script included in one page, why would I want to leverage the asset pipeline? Should I still want to? Should I not want to have page specific javascript files? If so, how about the javascript that needs to be called to initialize that particular page (e.g. in order to allow for unobtrusive javascript) and shouldn't be called anywhere else?

Where do the javascript and css files that I have written go? How do I make sure they get included in the head of the document? Do I need to add a yield block in the head of my application layout in order to get this to happen

Someone please help me to learn the standard and best-practices way of doing this.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a common.js and include it in the asset pipeline by adding it to the `application.js` ,Moreover,if you are not using `require_tree`,then you have to include files separately with `jQuery(function($)`